# PhpAmqpLib Getting 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - consumer ack timed out on channel 1', (0, 0),

Tags: celery, php-amqplib

After adding 'delivery_mode' => 2 started getting error Unrecoverable error: PreconditionFailed(406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - consumer ack timed out on channel 1', (0, 0), '') Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more

Intermittently its throwing this error and pod is getting restarted.